# Should I use unique_ptr or shared_ptr in this case?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

in the mainwindow of my QT app, I use a `std::shared_ptr` to hold a pointer to an instance of my network service which manages all the connections to multiple clients. Now, I have to pass this pointer to multiple sub windows so that they can communicate with the clients.

Do i better use a `std::shared_ptr` member variable in the main- and sub-windows and pass copy it when creating the subwindows, or is it better to use a `std::unique_ptr` and pass a raw pointer to the sub Windows, as the mainwindow will outlive the subwindows anyway?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think std::shared_ptr will be a better choice ,since you are talking about sub-windows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main practical difference is what happens when the mainwindow is destroyed while a subwindow still exists and is using the network service:

- If you use `unique_ptr` and pass raw pointers then you get undefined behavior.
- If you use `shared_ptr` then the network service remains until all subwindows are destroyed.

Now, if this condition is impossible by design then the undefined behavior is not inherently a problem. If the condition happens anyway due to a bug then it *might* help you to detect the bug if the network service is destroyed along with the main window, which would happen if you use `unique_ptr`. Using `unique_ptr` expresses that the mainwindow is the only thing that owns the network service, the others merely use it as directed by the mainwindow.

On the other hand, if you later change the design and want to make the condition legal, or if you want to use the subwindows in a different way that means there's no single network service object that they all use and that outlives them all, then it will be easier if you used `shared_ptr` from the start. Using `shared_ptr` expresses that all the windows share ownership of the network service.

I don't think it's possible to say in general whether you should try to make your code continue working in the face of "impossible conditions". In this case it's very cheap to do so (`shared_ptr` is more expensive to copy than a raw pointer, of course, but cheap compared with creating a subwindow, and the code is structured the same either way). It can be useful to have the flexibility to make the "impossible condition" happen under certain circumstances, for example when unit testing the subwindow code. So probably use `shared_ptr` for flexibility. If enforcing the lifetime constraint is a big deal for other reasons then you might not *want* any flexibility, in which case avoid writing code that will only ever hide bugs.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is a 3rd alternative you have not explored.

- Passing `shared_ptr` allows you to have multiple owners, however it seems in your case this is unnecessary
- Using `unique_ptr` and passing a raw pointer enforces a single owner, but in case of bug then you are faced with undefined behavior (a crash).

The 3rd alternative is to combine both approaches using `weak_ptr`:

- The main window *owns* the device in a `shared_ptr`
- The sub windows are handed down a `weak_ptr`

When the sub window needs to communicate using the device, they will use `lock()` on the `weak_ptr` to *temporarily* obtain a `shared_ptr`. You can then *assert* or *throw* if the `shared_ptr` is empty (it's a bug), and otherwise use it to communicate with the device, and then let it go as you are done.

---

**EDIT**: as Steve Jessop noted another assertion is useful (and achievable): ensuring that when the main window destroys the `shared_ptr` it was the last owner and the device is released (to protect against an accidental leak of ownership).

The naive way, asserting that it's `unique` before destruction, unfortunately suffers from a race-condition; between the call to `unique` and the actual destruction, a call to a `weak_ptr::lock` could create a new owner.

It can be done simply, however:

1. Create a new `weak_ptr` called `monitor` from your `shared_ptr`.
2. Reset the `shared_ptr`.
3. Call `monitor.lock()`, if it returns a non-null `shared_ptr` then there is an owner in the wild.

Comment: It's not possible to atomically test the refcount of a `shared_ptr` and destroy it, is it? I ask because there's a potentially useful second assertion you could make, that when the subwindow destroys  its `shared_ptr` it is not the last owner. You can just assert not `unique()` and then destroy, of course.

Comment: @SteveJessop: that is indeed interesting, I'll expand on this assertion in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The question about using `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` is mostly one of ownership. Will there be only one single owner at a time to the object? Or will there be multiple owners to the object?

In your case it seems like you want multiple owners, so then `std::shared_ptr` is the way to go.

***Don't*** use `std::unique_ptr` and then pass around the raw wrapped pointer. It will come back to bite you when you forget it and the `std::unique_ptr` object goes out of scope while someone else still have access to the raw pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like the network service is an object which
should exist for the life of your program.  In which case, it's
not certain that any type of smart pointer should be used; the
most obvious solution would be a local variable in `main`.  At
any rate, the first thing to ask yourself is what the lifetime
of the object should be.  If that lifetime corresponds to the
scope of `main` (or the scope of any other function), the local
variable is the way to go.  If that lifetime should correspond
to that of the main window, a member variable of the main window
would be the appropriate solution.  It all depends on how your
application specifies the object lifetimes (which is a design
issue, which can't be solved by low level programming
techniques).

About the only case you might need to use pointers is if the
type is polymorphic, and the actual type is not known until
runtime (e.g. because it is determined by entries in
a configuration file).  In this case, you'll have to manage the
lifetime yourself, but if it does correspond to a scope,
`std::unique_ptr` might be a good solution, since if not moved,
it precisely emulates the lifetime of a scoped variable.  (I'd
be very sceptical of `std::shared_ptr` here; the lifetime should
probably be deterministic, and not dependent on whether someone
happens to hold a pointer to it.  I can also imagine scenarios
where the network server would hold pointers to its clients,
with a risk of cycles.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, how can I access the local variable in `main()` from a QT window? I actually thought about making the service `singleton`, but there was a reason why I didn't want to, I don't remember why though.